# Correct use of L'Hospital's Rule.

Tags: limits

I know the limit I've evaluated is incorrect. But can you help me figure the step where I went wrong. 
$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\log x &=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\log x}x\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac1x\cdot x\log x\right)\\
&= \left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\right)\cdot\left( \lim_{x\to 0}x\log x\right)\\
&= \left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\right)\cdot\left( \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log x}{1/x}\right)\\
&= \left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\right)\cdot\left( \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}\right)\\
&= \left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\right)\cdot\left( \lim_{x\to 0}-x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac1x\cdot (-x)\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}(-1) = -1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Please write out the equation in MathJax. It doesn't take very long ...

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: What image? ${}{}$

Comment: Ok. Let me switch to my laptop.

Comment: Please use [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math

Comment: It would be appreciated if someone can edit the post to include the formatted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t split a limit into a product when the individual limits aren’t defined or are unbounded.

$$\color{red}{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}}$$

The limit above is not defined, so you can’t split the initial limit into a product of limits containing this.

Note that

$$\lim_{x \to 0^\color{blue}{+}}\frac{1}{x} = \color{blue}{+}\infty \color{red}{\neq} \lim_{x \to 0^\color{red}{-}}\frac{1}{x} = \color{red}{-}\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate limits like this only if each individual limit exists.  Since you have (for instance)

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x},$$

which doesn't exist, all of your acrobatics are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not defined, you have to use $\lim_{x\to0^+}$ since log$x$ is defined for positive $x$ only. Also, you can distribute limit over multiplication only if atleast one of them exists but we know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist (being $\infty$ on one side and $-\infty$ on other)

Hope it is helpful